# Running Instruments on iPod touch, device restart

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, ipod-touch, restart

I can't get my application running with instruments. I tried running through xcode with Product->Profile, Instruments starts, and then i select Time profile, iPod gets restart.
 I am on 10.7, xcode 4.2, iPod touch4 with iOS 5.0.1, and using 5.0 SDK. Need help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iPod just running out of memory.